# How to dynamically assign "is-active" class based on current focus in C#

Tags: c#, html, css

I have a class called "is-active" and it has a colored arrow that sticks out from the nav into the main content based on which link is the current active one.  The code runs a `foreach` and pulls all the categories from the database.  How do I get the "is-active" class to display only for the current link?  I know it works since I put it in the `openList` control and it displayed on all five categories, I just don't know how to get it to display on only the selected category.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Below is my code for the categories and link button:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        LiteralControl openingDiv = new LiteralControl("<div id='MainPanel'>");
        LiteralControl closingDiv = new LiteralControl("</div>");   

        this.Controls.Add(openingDiv);

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            LiteralControl openList = new LiteralControl("<li class='" + dr["CategoryColor"].ToString() + "'>");
            LiteralControl closeList = new LiteralControl("</li>");                

            Label lblNumber = new Label();

            LinkButton myLinkButton = new LinkButton();

            myLinkButton.Text = "<span class='number'>" + dr["CategoryNumber"] + "</span>"+ dr["CategoryName"].ToString();
            myLinkButton.CommandArgument = dr["Category_ID"].ToString();
            myLinkButton.Click += myLinkButton_Click;

            this.Controls.Add(openList);
            this.Controls.Add(myLinkButton);
            this.Controls.Add(closeList);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(closingDiv);
    }
    void myLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        Session["CategoryID"] = btn.CommandArgument;

        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);  
    }
```

Comment: The current link logic is what? The current link clicked by the user? If that is the case you are going to want to add and remove the class with javascript.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the current link that is clicked on by the user.  I am not strong in JS, but I will give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: Use jQuery, it will be worth the learning curve.